# How do I print my name 5 times?

Tags: javascript

I am super new to coding. Working my way through the first few lesson for havascropy in CodeAcademy. I have just learnt about for loops. I can use the following code to print form 1 to 5 but how do I use it to print my name 5 times?

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter = counter + 1) 
{
console.log(counter);
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` does the output. Because of the loop it is already called 5 times. Just change, what you want it to output.

Comment: `console.log("Nicholas")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++) 
{
   console.log("your name");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to write your name as a String inside `console.log()` instead of the variable `counter`.

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++) 
{
    console.log('Josh');
}
```

`counter` is just there to count how many times the loop needs to... well... loop ;-). Inside, you can do whatever you want - in this case: print your name into the browsers console.

Answer (score 3):

Try more recursion:

```js
(function loop(i) {
  if (i < 5) {
    console.log("Aadit M Shah");
    loop(i + 1);
  }
}(0));
```

Just my two cents, because everybody else answering this question have trite answers.

Comment: he is new to coding! and needs something easy!

Comment: Which is what the other answers are for!

Comment: `console.log('recursion, seriously?')`?

Comment: This isn't even better than the easy way.

Comment: @iKiWiXz Indeed. It's just more fun! =D

Answer (score 0):

A generic `repeat` function

```js
const repeat = n => f => x =>
  n > 0 ? repeat (n - 1) (f) (f (x)) : x;

// print your name 5 times
repeat (5) (name => (console.log(name), name)) ('なおみ');
```

Or using nothing but a couple lambdas, `console.log`, and a string containing your name

```js
(h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x))) (h => f => f (x => h (h) (f) (x)))
(f => x => n => (n => n (x => (a => b => b)) (a => b => a)) (x) (u =>
x) (u => (console.log(n), f ((n => f => x => n (g => h => h (g (f)))
(u => x) (u => u)) (x)) (n))) (x)) (f => x => f (f (f (f (f (x))))))
('なおみ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("Hello\n".repeat(10))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.